# Child Domain instead of port forarding

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

I would like to setup my ubuntu system to redirect to server ports based on the sub/child domain I use.

So everything comes in on port 443  (for security)
then have the following :
user.domain.com that would forward to 192.168.*.1 port 100
person.domain.com that you forward to 192.168.*.2 port 200

and so on

Is there a good tutorial for this, please.

Many Thanks

Comment: sounds like virtual hosts. You really should not redirect https.

Comment: Do all your hosts need ssl ? See https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts

Comment: Why shoudn't you forward ssl, @bodhi.zazen

Answer (score 2):

What you want is basically a reverse proxy, receiving conncetions from the world, and forwarding them to internal servers based on name. This can be achieved using Apache, nginx, varnish and a multitude of other servers.

I'd suggest sticking with nginx or Apache. They're easy to set up and efficient.

[This article](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) discusses proxying with nginx. As you can see, it has a fairly simple syntax. What you'd have to do is basically set up a vhost in nginx for every subdomain, and proxy all of it to the new location.

The browser visiting your page will only communicate with the proxy. The proxy will forward all requests to the internal server handling that subdomain.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for this and I will try this later on tonight I hope. looking forward to not having to alrewas remember all the different ports I use lol.